# confusion with trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus

\begin{align}
6 \sin^2 x&=1 & 0 \leq x \leq 2\pi\\
   \sin^2 x&=1/6\\
      \sin x&= 1/\sqrt6\\
         \sin a&=1/\sqrt6\\
            a&=0.420\\
\end{align}
              so $x$ is $0.420$ and $2.721$

According to the key at the back of the book there are supposed to be 2 more answers; $3.56$ and $5.86.$ Could someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: The sine could be negative too.

Comment: oh thank you, that completely slipped my mind

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve legibility

Comment: Think of the quadrants of a graph and how many radians everything translates to.

Answer (score 1):

If the trigonometric equation is supposed to be $6\sin^2x=1$,

$$\sin^2x=\frac{1}{6},$$ like you said. However, when taking square root of both sides, we must consider all square roots and not just the principal square root.

$$\sin{x}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$$
$$\sin{x}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$$
$$x=\sin^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The Solutions are given by $$x=\pi -\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor x=2 \pi -\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor x=\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor
   x=\pi +\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)$$